# Angular base href not showing up in the image URL

Tags: angular2-template

https://dev********.us/assets/images/login/login-bg.png

this is the actual url in the production server, in this path the images are not loading.
the reason is the base url is not appented with actual url.

even the   I added in the index.html.

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHskk.png)

After I build this project in the server using this command,
ng build --prod --base-href /enrollment/

Still this image not taking the base url...?

this is the result im expecting in the server.

https://dev*******.us/enrollment/assets/images/login/login-bg.png

in the production server